# Trying to change values in a field with a cursor

Tags: python, cursor, arcpy

We are trying to change the values in a column from a `shapefile` to create a new field/column with the new values. We've tried using a search and update cursor to accomplish this as well as a for loop and field calculator. **Does anyone have an idea for how to go about accomplishing this in a simplistic way?**

Here's a sample of our script in which we try to convert all of the items labeled "**Montane_Chaparal**" in the column to a new value "**Dry_Forest**" in the new column

```
veg = "Cal_Veg.shp"
field = ["WHRNAME"]

therows=arcpy.UpdateCursor(veg, field)

for therow in therows:
    if (therow.getValue(field)==" "):
        therow.setValue("Montane_Chaparral","Dry_Forest")
    therows.updateRow(therow)

print "Done."
```

I have also tried:

```
veg = "Cal_Veg.shp"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(veg,["WHRNAME","NewVeg"]) as SCursor:
    for row in SCursor:
        if row[0] == "Montane Chaparral": 
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(veg,["NewVeg"]) as ICursor:
                for new_row in ICursor: 
                    NewVeg = "Dry Forest"
                    ICursor.insertRow(new_row)
print "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend the more modern `da` [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) for your script, for a variety of reasons, but mainly for speed and efficiency.

It appears as if you are incorrectly running a nested cursor where all you need is a single Update Cursor. Try this.

```
veg = "Cal_Veg.shp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(veg,["WHRNAME","NewVeg"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "Montane Chaparral": # row[0] references "WHRNAME"
            row[1] = "Dry Forest"         # row[1] references "NewVeg"
        cursor.updateRow(row) 

print "done"
```